# '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command.."

Tags: node.js, cmd

I've installed Node and restarted my computer, added ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\ to my Paths, but when I run $ node -version in the command prompt to check the version it returns "'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `$`. It is just a prompt marker on Unix-type systems. It is tradition among the Unix folks when listing in instructions some commands to enter at the command line to precede a command with the `$`. It signals that it is a shell command, but when you type the command, you don't type it. So if you see:

```
$ node foo.js
```

You type `node foo.js` at the command line prompt, and not the `$`.

You might also see `#` sometimes, which again, traditionally, is a prompt but this one is associated with the `root` user. So it would precede a command to be executed as the user `root` on a Unix-type system.