# install telerik appbuilder cli from node command prompt as npm package

Tags: node.js, command-prompt, command-line-interface

" '$' is not recognize as an internal or external command " this is what i got from command prompt when trying to install app builder Cli(command line interface) in node command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You should leave off the `$` from the command you are typing at the command line. See the linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564181) for the details of what it means.

Comment: @OneKitten This answer *is* **the** answer. It is not a "critique" or a "clarification". The error message that the OP reported is exactly the one you get when you start your command with a `$` that has been mindlessly copied from instructions designed for *nix systems (which traditionally get an initial `$` when showing that commands to type at the command line).

Comment: @RubberDuck The **essential** part **is** there "Don't use `$`" is the **only** thing that one needs to know to get rid of the error message that the OP reported. The link to the other answer is **background knowledge** that is **not** essential to solving the problem.